# ListView en Widget

Tags: android, android-listview, android-widget

Estoy intentando aprender a hacer Widgets y quiero hacer uno con un listView.

En la Activity normal de la app yo hago lo típico de:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

AdapterLV adapter = new AdapterLV(getContext(),R.layout.fila, arrayList);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Pero cuando lo intento en el código del widget no me deja hacerlo

```
public class MiWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context,
                         AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                         int[] appWidgetIds) {

        //Aquí intento el findViewById y todo lo demás...

    }
}
```

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frmWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:padding="5dp">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".MiWidget" android:label="Mi Primer Widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/miwidget_wprovider" />
    </receiver>
</application>
```

¿Cómo lo tengo qué hacer?

Comment: como que no te deja hacerlo? te da algún error?

Comment: Si, claro, directamente al poner `findViewById()` me sale en rojo, y si le doy a sugerencias (alt+intro) me dice que cree el método...

Comment: Está implementado en tu layout?

Comment: Si, añadí el codigo del layout

Comment: puedes añadir el manifest también?

Comment: Manifest añadido (no se por qué no se añaden las primeras líneas de la etiqueta `<manifest>` en el post)

Comment: @Jmyebenes Antes de decidir agregar un ListView a tu Widget ya revisaste los tipos de widget que puedes crear https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html . Si agregas un ListView tienes previsto como se mostaría?

Answer (score 0):

En tu proveedor:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_NAME)) {
        // Abre tu actividad aquí.
    }
}
```

Si cada objeto en tu `ListView` necesita un extra diferente para ayudar al `onReceive`, crea el Intent necesario, puedes usar el `FillInIntent` por cada objeto o `item` en el `ListView`, en `getViewAt`:

```
// Dale valor a onClickFillInIntent
final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent();
final Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putInt(YourWidgetProvider.ACTION_EXTRA_ITEM, event.getId()); // retrieve this in onReceive with intent.getIntExtra(ACTION_EXTRA_ITEM, -1)
fillInIntent.putExtras(extras);
rv.setOnClickFillInIntent(R.id.listview_main_layout, fillInIntent);
return rv;
```

Comment: Sorry, pero no entiendo muy bien donde tengo que meter cada cosa... es decir, el onRecive si, aunque no se qué tengo que poner en ACTION_NAME ni que Activity tengo que abrir...  Del resto, ni idea de cómo va...